# Is there a way to take a variable out of its scope? - JAVA

Tags: java

I'm a student and would like to know if there is a way to take a variable out of its scope block to be used in a local scope? I am trying to code a store of some sort where the users are given a few options to choose what they want to buy, how much they want to buy, and give them the total payment for the same Item. Now outside the block scope, I want to give the overall total with how much they bought of each item. Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SariSariStore{
   public static void main (String [] args) {
   
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   int piattos = 20;
   int wRabbit = 1;
   int maxEM = 1;
   int nescafeO = 7;
   float iceW = 1.50f;
   
   System.out.println("Would you like to buy something? [Y/N]");
   char i = scanner.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
   do {
          System.out.println("==================================="
                     +"\n"+  "|          Sari Sari Mart         |"
                     +"\n"+  "==================================="
                     +"\n"+  "| What do you want to buy?        |"
                     +"\n"+  "|                                 |"
                     +"\n"+  "|    1) Piattos chips     20 Php  |" 
                     +"\n"+  "|    2) White Rabbit      1 Php   |"
                     +"\n"+  "|    3) Max extra menthol 1 Php   |"
                     +"\n"+  "|    4) Nescafe Original  7 Php   |"
                     +"\n"+  "|    5) Ice water         1.5 PhP |"
                     +"\n"+  "|    6) Exit                      |"
                     +"\n"+  "===================================");
          System.out.println("Please select option from the given choices: ");
          int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        
         if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 6){       
                
             if (choice == 1){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );
                 int quantity1 = scanner.nextInt(); 
                 int itotal1 = piattos * quantity1;
               System.out.println("Total price: " + itotal1 +" Php");  
            }else if (choice == 2){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );
                 int quantity2 = scanner.nextInt(); 
                 int itotal2 = wRabbit * quantity2;
               System.out.println("Total price: " + itotal2 +" Php");
            }else if (choice == 3){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );
                 int quantity3 = scanner.nextInt(); 
                 int itotal3 = maxEM * quantity3;
               System.out.println("Total price: " + itotal3 +" Php");
            }else if (choice == 4){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );
                 int quantity4 = scanner.nextInt(); 
                 int itotal4 = nescafeO * quantity4;
               System.out.println("Total price: " + itotal4 +" Php");
            }else if (choice == 5){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );
                 int quantity5 = scanner.nextInt(); 
                 float itotal5 = iceW * quantity5;
               System.out.println("Total price: " + itotal5 +" Php");
            }else if (choice == 6){ 
             }
             
        }else{
         System.out.println ("Sorry we do not have that item, please pick among the choices");
        }
        int Total = itotal1 +itotal2 +itotal3 +itotal4 +itotal6; // problematic statement 
        System.out.println ("Your total is:"+ Total + " Php"); 
        System.out.println ("Do you still want to buy something? [Y/N]");
        i = scanner.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
   }while (i == 'y');
   if (i =='n'){
     System.out.println("Thank you! Please come again");
   }
   
   }
}
```

Thanks :>

Comment: Just dont define them inside the if/else statements, but rather higher up, to be in the same scope as int total.

So it will look something like: 

int choice = xxxx;
int quantity1, total1, quantity2, total2, quantity3, total3 = 0;  

Then continue all the same logic, but quantity1 = = scanner.nextInt();

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask for. If you want to access your totals (itotal1 to itotal5) outside of the do-while loop, then why dont you declare the variables outside the do-while loop? ie declare it along with the prices under the scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use just one field for this? Like this:

```
         System.out.println("Please select option from the given choices: ");
         int choice = scanner.nextInt();
         int total = 0;
        
         if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 6){       
                
            if (choice == 1){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );

               int quantity1 = scanner.nextInt(); 
               total = piattos * quantity1;

               System.out.println("Total price: " + total +" Php");  
            } else if (choice == 2){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );

               int quantity2 = scanner.nextInt(); 
               total = wRabbit * quantity2;

               System.out.println("Total price: " + total +" Php");
            } else if (choice == 3){ 
               System.out.print("How many would you like to buy? " );

               int quantity3 = scanner.nextInt(); 
               total = maxEM * quantity3;

               System.out.println("Total price: " + total +" Php");
            }
            ...
             
        } else {
         System.out.println ("Sorry we do not have that item, please pick among the choices");
         System.out.println ("Your total is:"+ total + " Php");
        }
```

Also consider using [switch](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm#:%7E:text=A%20switch%20statement%20allows%20a,is%20checked%20for%20each%20case.) statement for multiple if statements